# How to get position (x,y) and number of particular objects or shape in a handdrawing image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network, object-detection, handwriting

first, I've learning just couple of week about image processing, NN, dll, by myself, so I'm really new n really far to pro. n sorry for my bad english.

there's image or photo of my drawing, I want to get the coordinates of object/shape (black dot) n the number around it, the number indicating the sequence number of dot.

[image: The image]

How to get it? How to detect the dots? Shape recognition for the dots? Number handwriting recognition for the numbers? Then segmentation to get the position? Or use template matching? But every dot has a bit different shape because of hand drawing. Use neural network? in NN, the neuron is usually contain every pixel to recognize an character, right? can I use an picture of character or drawing dot contained by each neuron to recognize my whole picture?

I'm very new, so I'm really need your advice, correct me if I wrong! Please tell me what I must learn, what I must do, what I must use.
 Thank you very much. :'D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem which can't be solved by a quick solution.

Here is how I would approach it:

1. Get a better picture. Your image is very noisy and is taken in low light with high ISO. Use a better camera and better lighting conditions so you can get the background to be as white as possible and the dots as black as possible. Try to maximize the contrast.
2. Threshold the image so that all the background is white and the dots and numbers are black. Maybe you could apply some erosion and/or dilation to help connect the dark edges together.
3. Detect the rectangle somehow and set your work area to be inside the rectangle (crop the rest of the image so that you are left with the area inside the rectangle). You could do this by detecting the contours in the image and then the contour that has the largest area is the rectangle (because it's the largest object in the image). Of course, this is not the only way. See this: [OpenCV find contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)
4. Once you are left with only the dots, circles and numbers you need to find a way to detect them and discriminate between them. You could again find all contours (or maybe you've found them all from the previous step). You need to figure out a way to see if a certain contour is a circle, a filled circle (dot) or a number. This is a problem in it's own. Maybe you could count the white/black pixels in the contour's bounding box. Dots have more black pixels than circles and numbers. You also need to do something about numbers that connect with dots (like the number 5 in your image)
5. Once you know what is a dot, circle or number you could use an OCR library ([Tesseract or any other OCR lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314060/c-tesseract-or-any-other-ocr-lib)) to try and recognize the numbers. You could also use a neural network library (maybe trained with the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)) to recognize the digits. A good one would be a convolutional neural network similar to [LeNet-5](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/multiples.html).

As you can see, this is a problem that requires many different steps to solve, and many different components are involved. The steps I suggested might not be the best, but with some work I think it can be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much :) That picture's only an example. The original is paper maps from hand drawing then scanned into HQ image. It means image will be contain street, segment, n other things simbol that usually on the maps. I've tried to threshold, image became more clear, but the dots became thinner (like from circle shape become ellipse or not perfect circle). Maybe it's not really problem like you said we see that dots have more black pixels than circles.

Comment: @lulu You're welcome. If you feel that I've answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer. [Read here why you should do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)